# Convert matrix with two "Y" columns to a list

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to clean up a script that will convert a matrix with two "Y" columns to a list.

Before
[image: Before]

After
[image: After]

```vb
Sub ConvertTable()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim cRng As Range
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim xOutRng As Range
    xTitleId = "ConvertTable"
    Set cRng = Application.InputBox("Select your Column labels", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    Set rRng = Application.InputBox("Select Your Row Labels", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Select your data", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    Set outRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    Set xWs = Rng.Worksheet
    k = 1
    xColumns = rRng.Column
    xRow = cRng.Row
    For i = Rng.Rows(1).Row To Rng.Rows(1).Row + Rng.Rows.Count - 1
        For j = Rng.Columns(1).Column To Rng.Columns(1).Column + Rng.Columns.Count - 1
            outRng.Cells(k, 1) = xWs.Cells(i, xColumns)
            outRng.Cells(k, 2) = xWs.Cells(xRow, j)
            outRng.Cells(k, 3) = xWs.Cells(i, j)
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

It only puts out Column A data (A, C, E). I need to add in a way to bring B2 down to H3. My current code ignores Column B all together.

Updated code with ranges

```vb
Sub ConvertTablewRef()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim cRng As Range
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim xOutRng As Range
    Set cRng = Range("A1:F1")
    Set rRng = Range("A1:B70")
    Set Rng = Range("C2:F70")
    Set outRng = Range("H1")
    Set xWs = Rng.Worksheet
    k = 1
    xColumns = rRng.Column
    xRow = cRng.Row
    For i = Rng.Rows(1).Row To Rng.Rows(1).Row + Rng.Rows.Count - 1
        For j = Rng.Columns(1).Column To Rng.Columns(1).Column + Rng.Columns.Count - 1
            outRng.Cells(k, 1) = xWs.Cells(i, xColumns)
            outRng.Cells(k, 2) = xWs.Cells(xRow, j)
            outRng.Cells(k, 3) = xWs.Cells(i, j)
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

This is the result of my code and not what I want. I need to see what is shown in the second picture above. Headers do not need to be there.
[image: after2]

Comment: I must confess that I do not understand your code, since you do not explain what selections you make to set these ranges using InputBox. At least, a comment for each line. Being the single one knowing what you are trying to do, it will be very difficult to receive any help, I am afraid... It is easy to obtain what you try showing, for the first row, except column headers, or for all the range which can be seen, but I cannot understand your code attempt. I would suggest you to forget about InputBoxes and use the exact ranges you try processing. You can use them in a later stage, if need help.

Comment: Should we understand that B and C share the same values for each date?

Comment: Are there more columns to the right, or all the range to be processed appears in your first picture?

Comment: These are the entire ranges as shown. The first picture is meant to be a "before" and second what I'm trying to achieve for "after". Column labels would be range A1:F1, row labels would be A1:B100. Data range would be the numbers C2:F100. This code is more for a grid with one y axis column and one x axis row. I am trying to add in another component where instead of A1 and B1 being horizontal they translate vertical and grab the corresponding value and date to the right.

Comment: @FaneDuru i added your requests to the post

Comment: OK. Please, test the code I posted. Now it is late in my country and I am closing my laptop. If something unclear or not working as you need, please ask for clarifications and I will answer tomorrow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It will accept some other columns with date and should be very fast, using arrays, working only in memory and dropping the resulted array at once:

```
Sub ConvertTable()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
 Dim arr, arrH, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long, L As Long, k As Long

 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 Set sh2 = sh.Next

 lastRow = sh.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 lastCol = sh.cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

 arr = sh.Range("A1", sh.cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Value
 ReDim arrFin(1 To 3, 1 To (UBound(arr) - 1) * (lastCol - 2) * 2 + 1)
 k = 2
 'arrfin headers:
 arrFin(1, 1) = arr(1, 1): arrFin(2, 1) = "Amount": arrFin(3, 1) = "Date"
 'processed data:
 For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
    For j = 3 To UBound(arr, 2)
       For L = 1 To 2
            If k Mod 2 = 0 Then
                arrFin(1, k) = arr(i, 1): arrFin(2, k) = arr(i, j): arrFin(3, k) = arr(1, j): k = k + 1
            Else
                arrFin(1, k) = arr(i, 2): arrFin(2, k) = arr(i, j): arrFin(3, k) = arr(1, j): k = k + 1
            End If
        Next L
    Next j
 Next i
 'drop the arrFin at once:
 sh2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin, 2), 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrFin) 
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much, this worked brilliantly! It'll also work great when I add more columns/rows which is perfect.

Comment: @spacej3di: Glad I could help! But I would recommend you to be more attentive when open a question, trying to put yourself instead of the ones (maybe) able to help. Your code could not be understood by nobody, in the way it was presented. Even if you, for unknown reasons, want using it in that way, you should adapt it to be also clear for other people, related to what you intend doing...